# How to disable wi-fi on Android device in Appium?

Tags: java, automation, appium

In our test case: I need to disable Wi-Fi at some specific point/action.

I have verified:

```
driver[deviceIndex].setConnection(Connection.NONE);
assertEquals(Connection.ALL, driver[deviceIndex].getConnection());
```

But it's not doing anything.

My expectation is "turning OFF wi-fi" and keeping Mobile Data ON.

Current code is doing no action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Apache common langs to your project.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.9

Comment: Cool, and then above method will work....right? or do i need to write any other method?

Comment: That's it. Just add the common langs and it should work.
There is also another solution for turning it off. You can execute that command in your code:
adb shell am start -n io.appium.settings/.Settings -e wifi off

Comment: it's not working bro. Added dependency and used same code as mentioned in question, still doing nothing.

Comment: What's the version of appium java client are you using?

Comment: Appium version:  1.12.1

Comment: Not the appium version. The appium's java client version.
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.appium/java-client/7.0.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193992/discussion-between-qa-palash-and-sharaf).

Answer (score 0):

In appium you can only toggle the wifi network using **driver.toggleWifi()** method. That means it will change wifi to off state if it is in on state and vice versa.
To use toggleWifi() method you must use androidDriver. If you are using AppiumDriver you can typecast it to AndroidDriver like following.

```
((AndroidDriver) driver).toggleWifi();
```

You can also use **setNetworkConnection()** method but it also has certain limitaions. The limitations are:

[image: Limitation of using setNetworkConnection]

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of driver you are using? You should use AndroidDriver if you are working on Android. Here are the working code for me.

```
// turn on all (data and wi-fi)
public void turnOnAllData() {
    driver.setConnection(Connection.ALL);

}

// turn off all (data and wi-fi)
public void turnOffAllData() {
    driver.setConnection(Connection.NONE);

}

// turn on airplane
public void turnOnAirplaneMode() {
    driver.setConnection(Connection.AIRPLANE);
}

// turn on data
public void turnOnMobileData() {
    driver.setConnection(Connection.DATA);
}

// turn on wi-fi
public void turnOnWiFi() {
    driver.setConnection(Connection.WIFI);

}
```

Comment: I am using "AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>" this one and tried setConnection but it's not performing any action. Is it possible issue with Custom UI (Oppo, MI)?